# addClass for some moments and the remove it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, addclass

I want to add class to a div and remove it after some moments. I used `setTimeout`  and I don't really know that if I'm right. The first part, I mean `addClass` works perfectly until I add `removeClass` inside the `setTimeout` method. So, here it goes my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('main/order') ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data, // $(this).serialize(); you can use this too
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            if(res) {
                classie.addClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' );
                var messageEl = theForm.querySelector( '.final-message' );
                messageEl.innerHTML = res;
                classie.addClass( messageEl, 'show' );

                setTimeout(classie.removeClass( messageEl, 'show' ), 5000);
                setTimeout(classie.removeClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' ), 6000);

            }
        }

   });
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `setTimeout`'s to this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    classie.removeClass( messageEl, 'show' )
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){
    classie.removeClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' )
}, 6000);
```

You need to pass a function into `setTimeout()` and in your code you were calling a function and passing the result in instead of passing the function itself.